# Store notifications data with saveMany Contents

Tags: laravel, notifications

So what I am trying to do is store notifications to the database with Notifiable, but I have a saveMany contents and I don't know how to declare the data in the notifications. getting a null from what I've declared like the picture below

[image]

this is my saveMany store

```
$post = new Post;

        $post->user_id = Auth::guard('webcontrol')->user()->id;
        $post->lob = $request->lob;
        $post->type = 'post';
        $post->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $post->is_published = $request->is_published;
        $post->published_at = ($request->published_at) ? $request->published_at : Carbon::now();
        $post->metas = '{}';

        $post->save();

        $post->contents()->saveMany([
            new PostContent([
                'lang' => 'id',
                'slug' => str_slug($request->contents['id']['title'], '-'),
                'title' => $request->contents['id']['title'],
                'body' => $request->contents['id']['body'],
                'image' => $request->contents['id']['image'],
                'tag' => $request->contents['id']['tag'],
                'metas' => serialize($request->contents['id']['metas']),
            ]),

            new PostContent([
                'lang' => 'en',
                'slug' => str_slug($request->contents['en']['title'], '-'),
                'title' => $request->contents['en']['title'],
                'body' => $request->contents['en']['body'],
                'image' => $request->contents['en']['image'],
                'tag' => $request->contents['en']['tag'],
                'metas' => serialize($request->contents['en']['metas']),
            ])
        ]);

        Notification::send($user, new OneSignalNotification($post));
        dd('done');
```

this is my Notification

```
class OneSignalNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    public $post;

    public function __construct($post)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }
    
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'body' => $this->post['body'], //this is where i confused how to declare the saveMany contents so its not returning null
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: So, when you send the notification you pass in the $post and then what you're trying to do is get the body property directly from $this->post['body']. Shouldn't you try getting it from where you saved it...  `$this->post->contents()`?

Comment: when i tried to do $this->post->contents(['body']) it returns nothing too

Comment: The way I see it, `$this->post->contents()` should return multiple PostContent objects, thats why you can't get the body property. Can you please `dd($this->post->contents()` and see what it returns?

Comment: How to display the dd() data on toDatabase function? i dont know how.

Comment: You don't have to dd() if you don't know how to do it. You can return `'body' => $this->post->contents()` instead of `'body' => $this->post['body']`

Comment: {"body":{}} it returns null like this

Comment: That's interesting. What if you change this line `Notification::send($user, new OneSignalNotification($post);` to `Notification::send($user, new OneSignalNotification($post->fresh()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but the issue is with the fact that you want to retrieve the body from the post, but the way I see it, the $post doesn't have a body property. The PostContent seems to have the body property, but the problem is that you saved many PostContent to the same $post, so therefore there are multiple body properties, one for each PostContent. So that's why I would recommend use the first() method to get the first PostContent from $post and then return it. If you want to return all the body property, you would have to get all of them and add them into an array or a string, or whatever you want. I hope this makes sense.

You should try using this:

```
$post = new Post;

$post->user_id = Auth::guard('webcontrol')->user()->id;
$post->lob = $request->lob;
$post->type = 'post';
$post->category_id = $request->category_id;
$post->is_published = $request->is_published;
$post->published_at = ($request->published_at) ? $request->published_at : Carbon::now();
$post->metas = '{}';

$post->save();

$post->contents()->saveMany([
    new PostContent([
        'lang' => 'id',
        'slug' => str_slug($request->contents['id']['title'], '-'),
        'title' => $request->contents['id']['title'],
        'body' => $request->contents['id']['body'],
        'image' => $request->contents['id']['image'],
        'tag' => $request->contents['id']['tag'],
        'metas' => serialize($request->contents['id']['metas']),
    ]),

    new PostContent([
        'lang' => 'en',
        'slug' => str_slug($request->contents['en']['title'], '-'),
        'title' => $request->contents['en']['title'],
        'body' => $request->contents['en']['body'],
        'image' => $request->contents['en']['image'],
        'tag' => $request->contents['en']['tag'],
        'metas' => serialize($request->contents['en']['metas']),
    ])
]);

Notification::send($user, new OneSignalNotification($post->fresh()));
dd('done');
```

And then inside the Notification, like I said, we take the first PostContent from the $post and get it's body property:

```
class OneSignalNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    public $post;

    public function __construct($post)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }
    
    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'body' => $this->contents()->first()->body,
        ];
    }
}
```